# What does the envelope sign after the author name mean?

Tags: publications

I'm in the process of writing a paper for an upcoming conference. The conference provides a LaTeX template which can be found here: [Information for Authors of Springer Computer Science Proceedings](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines).

Looking at the proceedings of the previous years I noticed a little envelope after the name of the first authors.

[image: Image of this text: "Maxine France-Pillois 1, 2 (✉)"...]

However, I was not able to figure out what it means. So my question is what is the meaning of the little envelope after the name of the first author?

Comment: Probably that they are the author to contact, the communicating author, about the paper.

Comment: And, in fact, the corresponding author need not be the first author.

Comment: [Full link to the paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-77610-1_5). I find the `{name1,name2}@domain.com` syntax to be jarringly pedantic, but maybe it's just a computer-science thing.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With Springer journals, the envelope simply indicates that they are the nominated corresponding author for the paper.

Sources: [this forum topic](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10276) and [a Springer 'Instructions to Authors' PDF](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OvHUJnQNGVkJ:https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/MCRE%2BIfA.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1500871-p1178310+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk).